# Can aptitude group or search for packages which nothing depends on?

Tags: aptitude

With aptitude:

I can *see* the number of reverse dependencies with `%r` in the display format string (preferences), but how can I group/limit the package list according to that count?

I want to see/filter/search all packages which nobody depends on.

Comment: Only installed packages or everything in the repositories?

Comment: @terdon: I don’t care. Installed is `~i` – I know how to add that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`%r` gives you the number of *installed* packages that depend on that package.

You can list the installed packages for which no installed package depends on with:

```
aptitude search '~i ! ~R ~i'
```

You can extend that to *recommends* and *suggests* with

```
aptitude search '~i ! ~R ~i ! ~Rrecommends:~i  ! ~Rsuggests:~i'
```

You can list packages that no package (installed or not) depend on with:

```
aptitude search '! ~R .'
```

If your point is to list packages that you can *safely* remove, then, as [pointed out by Braiam](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119728/can-aptitude-group-or-search-for-packages-which-nothing-depends-on/119743?noredirect=1#comment188156_119743), you may want to also exclude essential packages ([`~E`](http://aptitude.alioth.debian.org/doc/en/ch02s04s05.html#searchEssential)) and those with *required* priority (and possibly *important*).

In aptitude (preferably in flat-list view), press <kbd>ℓ</kbd> (lowercase `L`) and enter:

```
~i ! ~R ~i ! ~Rrecommends:~i  ! ~Rsuggests:~i ! ~E ! ~prequired ! ~pimportant
```

(once you remove packages, some more packages may pop up in that list once the packages that depended on them have been removed)

See also [`~g` (`?garbage`)](http://aptitude.alioth.debian.org/doc/en/ch02s04s05.html#searchGarbage), for the *packages which are not installed, or which were automatically installed and are not depended upon by any installed package*.

Comment: I would exclude essential and critical packages ;)

Comment: In my case, I was looking for transitional packages with no reverse dependencies. I group them with key `G`: `pattern(?any-version(~i ?or(~dtransitional,~ddummy) !~R~i) => trans. pkgs not depended on)` – To look in the description is not safe, but I think there is no better way.

Comment: @Robert, your transitional packages with come under `~g` if they are marked as automatically installed. Eventually they will come under `~o`, which selects obsolete packages, when they are removed from the repository. I don't think there is any reliable way to filter for them specifically though.

Comment: @Graeme, they where not all automatically installed (otherwise they would be gone). – And before they get obsolete might take years...