# Are there packages in Debian without any further dependencies?

Tags: package-management, dependencies

Sometimes apt installs dependencies of dependencies of ... (and so on) to the deepest required level. So I wonder, are there any packages without any further dependencies or is there a single package at the deepest level of the dependency tree on which all other packages depend?

Comment: @Paul_Pedant but the dependency tree does have loops. Consider `libc6` and `libcrypt1`...

Comment: @Paul_Pedant reverse dependencies aren’t relevant, this is a loop involving regular dependencies — `libc6` depends on `libcrypt1` which depends on `libc6`.

Answer (score 2):

```
aptitude search '!~v !?depends(.) !?predepends(.) !?recommends(.) !?suggests(.)'
```

Should list the non-virtual packages that neither depend on nor pre-depend on nor recommend nor suggest any package.

See [Can aptitude group or search for packages which nothing depends on?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/119728) for the packages that nothing depends on.

Answer (score 1):

I can't say for Debian but in Fedora there are certainly packages which don't depend on anything, e.g. `busybox` - it's built statically. I can imagine packages containing nothing but text files - those again may not depend on anything else installed prior. Then there's a kernel - read on.

There's a package called `filesystem` - it provides empty directories for a system to be installed in - it's a core package but only the `grub2-efi-x64` package directly depends on it.

Almost every package in any Linux distro *containing* binaries or/and libraries will depend on a C library providing core kernel APIs - it's usually `glibc`.

Then, there's the Linux kernel package which contains binaries but it doesn't depend on `glibc` because it needs to run the system even when your filesystems are not mounted yet. Does `glibc` depend on the `filesystem` package? Not really. There are boot loaders which again don't depend on glibc because they need to run early, e.g. GRUB, LiLo or ReFind.

Then you can easily create a library which exports interfaces but it doesn't use C routines, so it won't depend on glibc.

TLDR: there's a lot of variety and not a single package which all others depend on. And there are packages which do not need anything.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, there are.

I just created a short script (quick and dirty) checking this on **Debian**:

```
cd /var/lib/apt/lists
while read -r x; do
[[ ${y} == Package* && ${x} != Depend* ]] && echo "${y}"
y="${x}"
done < <( grep -h -E "^(Package|Depends):" *_Packages )
```

This will list all packages without a dependency.

On my system it found 7591 packages.

Comment: You forgot `Pre-Depends:`